# How do I vertically align the text to the middle using CSS?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Here is the  [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ssF5K/.)

Now, how to do I vertically align the text here so that it comes right in the middle of `li` element. I can do it by applying little `paadding-top` but in that case the top part of the `li` won't remain a link. Using `display:table-cell`, aligns all the `li` elements horizontally (which I don't want). So, what's the solution then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/ssF5K/1/).

**The Code:**

```
.menuItems a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: inherit;}
```

Comment: We enjoy these answers ;) +1

Comment: But now, I am not able to align it horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

Use line-height in .menuItems, with the same value of height, ex:

```
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
```

Comment: This will fail if OP has more than 1 line

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ssF5K/3/
```

CSS :

```
.menuItems{
position: relative;
border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 40px;
width: 85%;
padding: 0;
font-family: Geneva, 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
font-weight: 500;
text-align: center;
    line-height:40px;
}
```

Comment: It will fail if the word is longer than `brushes` and more than one word `brushes brushes brushes` Proof:http://jsfiddle.net/ssF5K/4/

Comment: What you have done is creating two different `<ul>`. What I am mentioning is using a single `<li>` in the same `<ul>` with a word which is longer like `brushesbrushes` and more than one word like `brushes brushes brushes`. Under these mentioned circumstances, it will fail.

Comment: in this class width:20%; so text overlaping now use this .leftNavBar{
background-color:#FFF;
    width: 50%;
padding-top: 40px;
float:left;
}

Comment: why are you manually aligning it by giving it a `width` and `padding`? When the word changes, will you all the time apply a different width and different padding??